# Identify location along .shp routelayer for Android app

Tags: android, gps, shapefile

I wish to make a simple Android app which displays current location along .shp route layer. I am a total beginner concerning Android app developement. I have this tool in Arcgis, it enables to indentify kilometer value at specific point, from the beginning of the road. The app should use GPS location and from that convert it to road distance and road number. Its a very good tool for reporting accidents or other road events (dead animal, fallen tree).
Where should i start? Maybe there are some tutorials? Is this app reasonable and doable?

Thank you in advance